# Installer project for ASP.NET Core MVC hosted as windows service

Tags: c#, deployment, asp.net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core project hosted as a windows service using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WindowsServices nuget. Now I want to add it to an existing setup project, but the problem is that I can't find a way to create a ServiceInstaller like I usually do with windows services. The workaround I'm using for now is creating a custom action which runs "SC create" and "SC delete" on uninstall from a new process, but that approach is very problematic on the long run. Does anybody know a way to create a ServiceInstaller for ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: Please be aware, there is no MVC6 (anymore). It's just called ASP.NET Core MVC (1.0 and 1.1 are the available versions). http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/